# Prove that $-\sqrt{c}<ab<0$ if $a^4-2019a=b^4-2019b=c$.

Tags: calculus, polynomials, contest-math, systems-of-equations, real-numbers

> Let $a, b$ be two distinct real numbers and let $c$ be a positive real number such that
> $a^4-2019a=b^4-2019b=c$.
> Prove that $-\sqrt{c}<ab<0$.

I attempted to solve this question using calculus, as follows:

As the problem is symmetrical (for a and b) we can state that $a \geq b$

$a(a^3-2019)=c$

$b(b^3-2019)=c$

$ba(b^3-2019)(a^3-2019)=c^2$

$ab=\frac{c^2}{(b^3-2019)(a^3-2019)}$

We also have that $a^4-2019a=b^4-2019b$

Lets create a function $f$, such that $f(x)=x^4-2019x$ for any real number $x$

Then $f'(x)=4x^3-2019$

This equation has its minimum at point $x=\sqrt[3]{\frac{2019}{4}}$ and is declining in the range $x\in (-\infty, \sqrt[3]{\frac{2019}{4}}]$ and inclining in the range $x\in[\sqrt[3]{\frac{2019}{4}}, +\infty)$ and hence it is also 1-1 in these ranges.

Since $a^4-2019a=b^4-2019b$, then from the above, either a=b (which is impossible, as they are distinct numbers, from the problem statement), or $a>\sqrt[3]{\frac{2019}{4}}$ and $b<\sqrt[3]{\frac{2019}{4}}$.

So we have that $a>\sqrt[3]{\frac{2019}{4}}$ and $b<\sqrt[3]{\frac{2019}{4}}$.

From this and the fact that $c>0$ we have that $a(a^3-2019)>0$, and since $a>0$ then $a^3-2019>0$

Now all that remains, is to prove that $b<0$ while $a>0$. From the above we have that $a>0$, so all we have to do now is show that $b<0$.

If $\sqrt[3]{\frac{2019}{4}}>b\ge0$, then $b^3<2019$, but since $a^3-2019>0$ and the fact that $ab=\frac{c^2}{(b^3-2019)(a^3-2019)}$, then $ab<0$.

Otherwise, if $b<0$, then we have that $b^3<0<2019$, and since $a>0$ we have that $ab<0$. This concludes the proof for the right part of the inequality.

Now for the left part of the inequality, we have the following:

$\sqrt{c}=\sqrt{a^4-2019a}$

so

$-\sqrt{c}=-\sqrt{a^4-2019a}$

so we only need the following to be true:

$-\sqrt{a^4-2019a}<ab$

so

$a^4-2019a>a^2b^2$

$a^3-2019>ab^2$

but we have that $a^3-2019=\frac{b^4-2019b}{a}$

so we only need for the following to be true $\frac{b^4-2019b}{a}<ab^2$

$b^4-2019b<a^2b^2$

$b^3-2019>a^2b$ (since $ab<0$ and $a>0$ then $b<0$)

but we have that $a\ge b$, so we have that $a^2b \ge b^3>b^3-2019$, so the above holds true.

I believe that I have just proven the inequality, however I am not completely certain. I have read it many times and I feel comfortable with my solution, however this is my first time writing such a solution, so I wanted to share it with the community, ask to make sure that it is correct and if possible could someone also show me a simpler method to solve this question?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Will you post other problems also?

Comment: I don't currently have any in mind, but as I come across them, I definitely will

Comment: I was about to post another question, but for some reason, I am not allowed to. I haven't received any down votes in the last week, my last few posts haven't had negative feedback, why am I not allowed to post questions?

Comment: I accidently wrote that I haven't had down-votes for one week, it has actually been a few months since my last downvote

Comment: not sure, very weird

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that, since $a\ne b$ $$a^4-b^4= 2019(a-b)\implies (a^2+b^2)(a+b)=\color{red}{2019}$$

If we add both equations we get:

\begin{align}2c &= a^4+b^4-\color{red}{2019}(a+b) \\
&= a^4+b^4-(a+b)^2(a^2+b^2)\\
&= -2ab(a^2+ab+b^2)
\end{align}
Since $a^2+ab+b^2>0$ we have $ab<0$. Further

\begin{align}c &= -ab(a^2+ab+b^2)\\
&> -ab(2|ab|+ab)\\
&= -ab(-2ab+ab)\\
& = a^2b^2
\end{align}

So $c>a^2b^2$ which means $-\sqrt{c}<ab$

Comment: Yes, first part RHS it is, but not sure for the LHS.

Comment: Please tell me what you haven't understood, so that I can try to explain it to you

Comment: You don't have to accept my answer yet, wait perhaps you will get better one.

Comment: I like your answer, thank you

Comment: I asked on the meta and from the looks of things, I need more upvotes, in order to be able to post again (just imagine I was bout to upload another JBMO solution i had done, and was about to post it up, when I saw that I can't upload for another six months, unless I get a lot more upvotes). I can share my solution with you if you like, if you give me your email address, or messenger details.

Answer (score 1):

$x^4-2019x>0$ gives $x>\sqrt[3]{2019}$ or $x<0,$ which gives $ab<0$.

Now, since $a\neq b$ and $a^4-2019a=b^4-2019b,$ we obtain $$a^3+a^2b+ab^2+b^3=2019$$ or
$$(a+b)(a^2+b^2)=2019,$$
which gives $$a^4-(a^3+a^2b+ab^2+b^3)=c$$ or
$$\sqrt{c}=\sqrt{-ab(a^2+ab+b^2)}$$ and it remains to prove that $$\sqrt{-ab(a^2+ab+b^2)}>-ab$$ or
$$a^2+ab+b^2>-ab$$ or $$(a+b)^2>0,$$ which is true bacause $a+b\neq0$.

Comment: Thank you, your solution us far neater than mine, but please tell me, is my solution correct as well?

Comment: Your first sentence is a bit fast in its conclusion that no *two* positive roots exist.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen $f$ is a convex function, $f(0)=0$, $f(\sqrt[3]{2019})=0$, $f$ decreases on $(-\infty,0]$ and $f$ increases on $[\sqrt[3]{2019},+\infty),$ which says the equation $f(x)=c$, where $c>0$ has two real roots exactly. $a$ and $b$ are roots. Thus, $ab<0$ because one of them is negative and other is greater than $\sqrt[3]{2019}.$ Is it clear now?

Comment: In my previous comment $f(x)=x^4-2019x$.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen Also, $f$ is a continuous function, $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow-\infty}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=+\infty$.  I wait your reaction...

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen I wait your reaction...

Answer (score 0):

$a,b$ are distinct real roots of the polynomial
$$\tag1 x^4-2019x-c$$
Between any two real roots of $(1)$, the derivative $4x^3-2019$ has a root, but the only of that is $\sqrt[3]{\frac{2019}4}$.
*At this point we stop using calculus.*
From the above, exactly two of the roots of $(1)$ are real; the other roots $u,v$ are non-real complex conjugates.
We observe that $u,v$ cannot be non-zero purely imaginary: At imaginary $x$, $(1)$ produces real $x^4-c$ plus non-zero imaginary $-2019x$, so not zero.

We know from the coefficients that
$$ a+b+u+ v=0$$
$$ ab+au+av+bu+bv+uv=0$$
$$ abu+abv+auv+buv=2019$$
$$abuv=-c$$
Using $s:=uv=\|u\|^2>0$ and $t:=u+v=2\operatorname{Re}(u)\ne 0$(!), we can turn these equations into
$$ \tag1a+b=-t$$
$$ \tag2ab-t^2+s=0$$
$$ \tag3abt-ts=2019$$
$$ \tag4abs=-c$$
From $(4)$, $$\tag5ab=-\frac c{s}<0,$$ which is already half of the desired result.
From $(2)$, $ab+s=t^2>0$ so that $s> -ab$. Back in $(4)$,
$$ c=-abs=(-ab)s> (-ab)(-ab) $$
so that
$$\tag6 -\sqrt c< ab.$$

Comment: This is competition for kids $\leq 15,5$ years, so they mostly don't know even what polynomial is.